# jQuery dataType:

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I have an odd problem regarding jQuery dataType.

I have a very simple PHP program that returns (echo's) an XML file (string).  Looks like this:

```
$xmlFile = "sampleXMLFile.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);     
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

My client/javascript code calls the php program via ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "myPHPFile.php",   
    dataType: "xml",
    success: myCompleteFunction,
    complete: mySuccessFunction,
    failure: function(data) {
        alert("Problem getting XML");
        } });
});
```

The "myCompleteFunction" takes the XML and simply writes the first node into a div element, like this:

```
function myCompleteFunction(xml)
{
      $(xml).find("Row").each(function()
      {
        $("#result3").append($(this).attr("myrow"));
      });
}
```

OK - in IE 8, this works fine.  In Firefox and Chrome I get **no results**.  However, if I change the dataType to **"html"** I get correct results in Firefox and Chrome and then get **no results** in **IE**.'

Continue to go crazy with this.  Do I actually need to put conditional logic for the browsers?

The **dataType:** option explained in the jQuery manual seems clear enough.  I even tried to leave dataType out

> (per manual: If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME
>   type of the response)

I also tried multiple types - e.g. "text xml".  No good.

Anyone ever run into this problem?  Any direction would be appreciated.

Thank you.

p.s. I know I can read an XML file in jQuery.  The resultant XML from the PHP program would be substantially more involved.  I only used that as an example.

---

Updated:

Well, I saw Phil's comment about producing something before XML data sent.  There was certainly nothing obvious.  I removed a blank line above my first `<?php` line.  This has somehow worked!  Still seems odd to me.  So my new, tighter PHP code is now:

```
<?php
// Load XML   
$xmlFile = "sample.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);     
header('Content-type: text/xml'); 
echo $xml->saveXML(); 
?>
```

I will also pay mind to your other suggestion about properly handling jQuery.ajax() callbacks.  Thanks.

I very much appreciate your help w/this!!

Answer (score 3):

Stick with the "xml" `dataType` and add this to your PHP file before the `echo`...

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

Also, you seem to be mixing up some of the `jQuery.ajax()` callbacks.

- Use `success` to handle the returned data.
- Use `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` (not `failure`) to handle HTTP errors
- Use `complete` to execute some tasks after `success` and `error` callbacks have executed

Comment: Tried this w/no luck
<pre>
$xmlFile = "sample.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);     
header('Content-type: text/xml');        
echo $xml->saveXML(); 
</pre>
Get this and no results.
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Comment: @Rob In that case, you have something producing output before the XML data is sent. You definitely do not want this. Also, edit your question to add more code / messages. Don't try and post it in comments

Comment: Well, I saw Phil's comment about producing something before XML data sent.  There was certainly nothing obvious.  I removed a blank line above my first `<?php` line.  This has somehow worked!  Still seems odd to me.  

I will also pay mind to your other suggestion about properly handling jQuery.ajax() callbacks.  Thanks.

I very much appreciate your help w/this!!